# Click function not working with dynamically created selector on Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I'm working on a page where I load list elements with the youtube api. In my code I've got an empty ul which gets filled dynamically on load:

```
 <ul class="videos" data-plist="PLquImyRfMt6fnpIb9VR9c6VLZwYs_OyWL" data-maxres="20"></ul>
```

Now I have a click function in which I need to use one of the dynamically created list elements as a trigger. It works everywhere except on Safari. Is there a way to make this work, so that Safari recognizes even those elements? I tried everything, doc ready, on load, simple function, top, end of script etc.

EDIT
Here comes some code

That's how I get my list items

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
            part: 'contentDetails',
            forUsername: channelName,
            key: 'AIzaSyCu8N1RGBaExofEQtBZHMMpAYNxvirhIBM',
        },
        function(data) {
            $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                var pid = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;
                getVids(pid);
            });
        });

    function getVids(pid) {
        $("[data-plist]").each(function() {
        var vidResults = $(this).data('maxres');
        var vidPlaylist = $(this).data('plist');
        var mylist = $(this);
        var staffel = mylist.prev().clone().find('h2').children().remove().end().text();


$.get(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems", {
                    part: 'snippet',
                    maxResults: vidResults,
                    playlistId: vidPlaylist,
                    key: 'AIzaSyCu8N1RGBaExofEQtBZHMMpAYNxvirhIBM'
                },
                function(data) {
                    $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                        var videoTitle = item.snippet.title.substring(8);
                        var videoDesc = item.snippet.description;
                        var videoThumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url;
                        var videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;

                        $.get(
                            "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos", {
                                part: 'statistics',
                                id: videoId,
                                key: 'AIzaSyCu8N1RGBaExofEQtBZHMMpAYNxvirhIBM'
                            },
                            function(data) {
                                $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                                    var views = item.statistics.viewCount;
                                    var output = '<li class="mix"><a class="yt-vid" href=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId + '?&amp;showinfo=0&amp;controls=0\" target="screen"><div class="thumb" style="background-image: url('+videoThumb+');"></div><div class="caption"><h3>' + videoTitle + '</h3><small>' + views + ' views</small></div></a><div class="infohide" style="display: none;"><a class="js-open-modal" href="#" data-modal-id="' + videoId + '"><small>' + staffel + '</small>' + videoTitle + '</a><div id="' + videoId + '" class="modal-box" style="display: none;"><header><h3>' + videoTitle + '</h3></header><div class="modal-body"><p>' + videoDesc + '</p></div></div></div></li>';

                                    $(mylist).append(output);
                                });
                            });
                    });
                });
        });
    }
});
```

When I copy the output I get into my index file, as static content, everything works fine. The click function I use does not work when I get the content from the  http request.

```
var trigger = $('.mix');

$(trigger).click(function() {
        alert('click');
         // Other stuff which seems not to be relevant
    });
```

I tried to wrap the click function in document ready, window load and I placed it on different positions. Of course after the main function to create the output...

Comment: You didn't post the most important thing, your code.

Comment: Ok I thought I could post this as a general question. I'll add my code in short, I just need to get back at my desk. Sry.

Comment: The real problem is how you bind event handler, so the code is needed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/97q31rtm/). Yes even I agree that if you share your code, it would be easy for us to understand the problem and help you with solution.

```js
function createLI(){
    var str = "";
    for (var i=0; i<7; i++){
     str += "<li id='li_" +i+"'>Item " +i+ "</li>";
    }
 $("#list").html(str);
}
 
function registerEvents(){
    for (var i=0; i<7; i++){
  $("#li_"+i).on("click", function(){
         $("#lblResult").text(($(this).text()));
        })
    }
}
(function(){
 createLI();
    registerEvents();
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list"></ul>

Clicked LI element: <span id="lblResult"></span>
```

#### Edit

I believe issue is when you register event, elements are not yet rendered, and may cause issue. I have simulated this issue. Try creating a callback and call it once elements are rendered.

```js
function createLI(){
    var str = "";
    for (var i=0; i<7; i++){
     str += "<li id='li_" +i+"' class='mix'>Item " +i+ "</li>";
    }
 $("#list").html(str);
}
 
function registerEvents(){
    //for (var i=0; i<7; i++){
    var e = $(".mix");
  $(e).on("click", function(){
         $("#lblOutput").text(($(this).text()));
        })
    //}
        
    $("#btnAdd").on("click", function(){
     $("#list").append("<li class='mix'>New element </li>")
    })
}
(function(){
 createLI();
    registerEvents();
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list"></ul>
<button id="btnAdd">Add element</button>

Clicked LI: <span id="lblOutput"></span>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know if it will help but instead of `var trigger = $('.mix')` try `trigger = '.mix'`.

Comment: I believe issue is event is registering before elements are rendered. I have updated my answer to show that.

Comment: That's it, worked! I called registerEvents after the complete output was rendered. Thanks very much :)